# What is causing Mint 18.1 "grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/" and following installation failure?

Tags: linux-mint, ssd-hdd-hybrid

The SSD is set to ACHI (whatever it is, it was automatically set).
Secure boot is set to Other OS (only other choice).

***Linux only. No Windows. Hate Windows. No dual boot. Microsoft hasn't touched my computer in years. Windows can suck it.***

I formatted both SSD and HDD drives to GPT.
- Corsair 30GB SSD (putting `/` and `swap` on here)
- Old, ~300GB HDD. No problems with the drive have been found. (putting `/home` here)

The live Mint USB isn't corrupt. I did the checksum before installing, and have done multiple checks on the USB before booting.

Installing Mint in UEFI mode is resulting in "**grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/**". Any forum I found on this error has not had a solution compatible with my problem. That package doesn't appear to exist. The installer ***will fail*** upon this message occurring. I have an internet connection. It's hardwired... (insert Metallica reference here). I can cruise the interwebs during the live boot.

Installing Mint in legacy, *not* UEFI, is resulting in no OS being found.

**Specs:**
- 18.1 Cinnamon (3.2.6) 64-bit
- AMD FX-8350 8 core x4
- 8GB RAM
- AMD/ATI Turks XT, Radeon HD 6670/7670

I am not sure what the *hell* is going on anymore.

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an EFI System partition with FAT32 on the SSD (where it's booting) worked.

From this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/891904/221847

Comment: I can confirm this works on a non-SSD hard disk as well. I installed it without any internet connection.